# String not changing when I do multiple if statements on it in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
    let re_alef = /([\u0621-\u064A]ا+)/g;
    let re_ya2 = /([\u0621-\u064A]ي+)/g;
    let re_waw =/([\u0621-\u064A]و+)/g;
    let match =text.match(re);
```

This is my variables I have done some regex in arabic and in need to change the text letters and their colors from an input

```
match.forEach(element => {
let el = element.split("");
if(re_alef.test(element) && element.length >3){
        // console.log(element.replace(/([\u0621-\u064A]ا+)/g , '<span class="clr-red">$1</span>'));

        result += element.replace(re_alef , '<span class="clr-red">$1</span>') + ' ' +
        element.replace(re_ya2 , '<span class="clr-red">$1</span>') + ' ';
       }
       else if(re_ya2.test(element) && element.length >3){
        // console.log(element.replace(/([\u0621-\u064A]ا+)/g , '<span class="clr-red">$1</span>'));

        result += element.replace(re_ya2 , '<span class="clr-red">$1</span>') + ' ';
       }
       else if(re_waw.test(element) && element.length >3){
        // console.log(element.replace(/([\u0621-\u064A]ا+)/g , '<span class="clr-red">$1</span>'));

        result += element.replace(re_waw , '<span class="clr-red">$1</span>') + ' ';
       }
       else{
        result += '<span class="clr-black">' + element + ' </span>';
       }
    });
```

Here is my code when I change the color of letters it changes but when I have a word that I already changed in an if statement, the other time I want to change the colors it doesn't as it has already passed through the if statement needed so I want to join all in one statement.
How can I do that?

Example output:

```
العالمية
```

In this word the ال are getting colored which is what I want but when this is done in another if I am asking it to change the color of عا this which is done right if I remove the code of the previous if

Any help would be appreciated!Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexes are good. In terms of replace, simply chain replace as many times as needed on your input text. There is no need to test for the string length, the regex will fail anyway if too short. Here is a working example:

```js
let text = 'العالمية';
console.log('text:   ' + text);
$('#text').html(text);
let re_alef = /([\u0621-\u064A]ا+)/g;
let re_ya2 = /([\u0621-\u064A]ي+)/g;
let re_waw =/([\u0621-\u064A]و+)/g;
let result = text
  .replace(re_alef , '<span class="clr-red">$1</span>')
  .replace(re_ya2 , '<span class="clr-green">$1</span>')
  .replace(re_waw , '<span class="clr-blue">$1</span>');
console.log('result: ' + result);
$('#result').html(result);
```

```css
.clr-red {
  color: red;
}
.clr-green {
  color: green;
}
.clr-blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```